# Is there any way to obtain distinct values across all the columns from within a table in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have tried to get the list of column names from a particular table using 
`Select column_name
from projectname.tablename.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name = 'something'`.

I am not sure if the right approach is to loop across all the column name while getting distinct values for each or if there is a different methodology to follow in BigQuery.

Expecting the result to be :

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
1     4    7
2     5    8
3          9
           11
```

The query must return the distinct values across all the columns irrespective of difference in length of the values.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how practical your requirement is but for relatively small tables it might work - so below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION DISTINCT_VALUES (arr ANY TYPE) AS (
  ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT el FROM UNNEST(arr) AS el ORDER BY el)
);
SELECT 
  DISTINCT_VALUES(col1) col1,
  DISTINCT_VALUES(col2) col2,
  DISTINCT_VALUES(col3) col3
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ARRAY_AGG(col1) OVER() col1,
    ARRAY_AGG(col2) OVER() col2,
    ARRAY_AGG(col3) OVER() col3
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  LIMIT 1
) t
```

if to apply to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION DISTINCT_VALUES (arr ANY TYPE) AS (
  ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT el FROM UNNEST(arr) AS el ORDER BY el)
);
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 col1, 4 col2, 7 col3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 5, 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 4, 9 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 5, 11 
)
SELECT 
  DISTINCT_VALUES(col1) col1,
  DISTINCT_VALUES(col2) col2,
  DISTINCT_VALUES(col3) col3
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ARRAY_AGG(col1) OVER() col1,
    ARRAY_AGG(col2) OVER() col2,
    ARRAY_AGG(col3) OVER() col3
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  LIMIT 1
) t
```

result is

[image]

So, I think more reasonable way is to get result like below

[image]

which can be achieved with below query

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT 'col1' col, col1 value FROM `project.dataset.table` UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 'col2', col2 FROM `project.dataset.table` UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 'col3', col3 FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

in case if different columns have different data types  - you can CAST them to STRING as in below example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT 'col1' col, CAST(col1 AS STRING) value FROM `project.dataset.table` UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 'col2', CAST(col2 AS STRING) FROM `project.dataset.table` UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 'col3', CAST(col3 AS STRING) FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Final notes: if number of columns large enough to type in all above queries manually - you can easily script them - see example in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61716652/5221944