# Concat values from similar columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, jira

I'm exporting my data from Jira into BigQuery which is flattening the labels into columns enumerated by the possible occurrences.

Is there a better way to join columns that are similar rather than specifying each column(as doesn't scale if we add a new label)?

**Current implementation**

```
SELECT
  ARRAY_TO_STRING([Custom_field__Environment_s__affected__1, Custom_field__Environment_s__affected__2,Custom_field__Environment_s__affected__3,Custom_field__Environment_s__affected__4,Custom_field__Environment_s__affected__5,Custom_field__Environment_s__affected__6,Custom_field__Environment_s__affected__7,Custom_field__Environment_s__affected__8], ', ')
FROM
  `DATASET.Jira.All Jira Issues`
```

Case:

**Jira - Environments Affected Labels**

- Production
- Staging
- Development
- etc. (8 in total)

**BigQuery - Current Output**

| ticket_name | Custom_field__Environment_s__affected__1 | Custom_field__Environment_s__affected__2 | Custom_field__Environment_s__affected__3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TICKET-1 | Production | Staging |  |

**BigQuery - Desired Output**

| ticket_name | environments_affected |
| --- | --- |
| TICKET-1 | Production, Staging |

**I've got:**

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `[PROJECT_ID.]DATASET_ID`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
  table_name='All Jira Issues' AND
  column_name LIKE 'Custom_field__Environment_s__affected__%'
```

**Output**

| table_name | column_name |
| --- | --- |
| All Jira Issues | Custom_field__Environment_s__affected__1 |
| All Jira Issues | Custom_field__Environment_s__affected__2 |
| All Jira Issues | Custom_field__Environment_s__affected__3 |
| ... | ... |

Unsure from here how I should get the row values from the columns to then format into a single column separated with commas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic Column Names in BigQuery SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61710854/dynamic-column-names-in-bigquery-sql-query)

Comment: Or this one https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-dynamic-sql-in-bigquery-8c04dcc0f0de

Comment: Pretty much combine those 2 links and run it with https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate

Answer (score 0):

you can use `string_AGG`

```
SELECT
  table_name,STRING_AGG(column_name,','  ORDER BY column_name) 
FROM
  `[PROJECT_ID.]DATASET_ID`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
  table_name='All Jira Issues' AND
  column_name LIKE 'Custom_field__Environment_s__affected__%'
GROUP BY  table_name
```

Comment: Ty, am looking for the values behind the columns so that I don't need to specify them individually. 

I'm wondering if a nested select to fetch the columns that are alike first with "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS" and then from the table without specifying the columns within the FROM would allow me to access the values.